# Can I choose another hat?

Tags: discussion, winterbash, winterbash-2015

My hat looks like a cheeseburger with a cherry on top.  Some of the other hats are really neat!  Is there anything I can do to get a hat with more je ne sais quoi?  Or do I just have to wait until next year?

Comment: Up close it looks like a cheeseburger with a drop of blood on top—very edgy.

Comment: @Sven Yargs  That makes all the difference.  I will wear it with relish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Winter Bash](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/?cb=1) announcement for more details. You can change your hat by:

1. Earning a new hat.
2. Selecting the new hat from the hat menu (snowflake).
3. Clicking "Wear Hat" on the hat display.

You can adjust how your hat looks by using the "show controls" checkbox and fiddling with the widgets.

Comment: Hi Kitz. Can I only "wear" one hat at a time?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Yes, you may only wear one hat at a time.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy - But as you might imagine, you can change your hat as often as you'd like.

Comment: @J.R. Technically, you can only change it every ten seconds. So as often as you want *in ten second intervals*.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox - Ten seconds!?? What is this, a [wardrobe change?](http://www.playbill.com/news/article/watch-kelli-oharas-47-second-quick-change-during-her-tony-performance-video-350830) Or a [Formula-1 pit stop?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7t-QUNZyzc) ;^)

Comment: @BiscuitBoy - But if you really want to monkey around with it, you can wear a [different hat](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r?tab=profile) on a [different exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/18220/j-r?tab=profile).